# Cannot set label style in jQuery.append()?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a textbox and a button. When the button i clicked, the textbox contents are appended to  `<body>` using `append()` method in jQuery. Also, while appending, I'm trying to set a `style` (namely, `border-style`) to the label that I'm appending. The following code does not do what I expect:

```
<style>
.myStyle{
    border-style:solid;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        var text=document.getElementById('txt1').value
        $("body").append("<br><label class="myStyle">"+text+"</label>");
    });
});
</script>
<input id="txt1" type="text">
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

Adding the `<div>` tag in the `append` part is also to no avail. The following does, but the first labelbox does not get a margin:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        var text=document.getElementById('txt1').value
        $("label").css("border-style","solid");
        $("body").append("<br><label>"+text+"</label>");
    });
});
</script>
<input id="txt1" type="text">
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

What's the deal with `append()`-ing and styling elements? What am I missing?

Comment: I recommend to read [this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to learn how to debug JavaScript. Syntax errors are easy to detect, because the browser will tell you about it. Regarding the second part of the question: `$("label").css("border-style","solid");` selects all **existing** `label` elements and changes their `border-style` property. It does not affect any `labels` elements you create *after* that.

Comment: Right. Using chaining,how would I achieve the same effect in a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("body").append("<br><label class="myStyle">"+text+"</label>");
//---------------^-----------------^
// These are the same type of quotes

$("body").append('<br><label class="myStyle">'+text+'</label>');
//---------------^---------------------------^------^--------^
// Swap these four out with single quotes
```

You should have noticed in your syntax highlighting, the myStyle becoming black, showing a break in the string.
Also I recommend a better editor if your current one isn't showing you such errors. Personally, I use WebStorm/PHPStorm.

Also, if you're going to use jQuery, then use jQuery.

```
var text = $('#txt1').val();
```

Comment: Yeah, got the crux of my problem. However, I noticed that with your code, nothing appears(in the browser). However, changing it to: 
`$("body").append('<br><label class="myStyle">text</label>');` seems to show what I want. Is that how single quotes work?

Comment: Nope - that shouldn't work. Are you 100% sure? Make sure you change all 4 of the double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: @black_stallion: That would literally show the word "text", rather than showing the value of the `text` variable you assigned the value to. ahren's code shows the value stored in `text`.

Comment: Do you have a <body> element?

Comment: @ahren,@T.J. Crowder: I too was surprised. Well, I have no idea how that happened. Probably some typo on my part. It works perfectly now thanks!

Comment: @iKindred: Sure it does. The code works just fine. Was most likely a typo on my part.